# Symmetric random walk and convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, random-walk, independence

I'm trying to solve the following:

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded real value sequence and let $Y_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $P(Y_n=1)=P(Y_n=-1)=1/2$. Let $$X_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nY_ka_k$$
>   and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_0,\dots,X_n)$
>
> 1. Show that $X_n$ converges in $L^2$ if and only iff $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2<\infty$
> 2. Compute $\langle X\rangle_n:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1}-X_k^2|\mathcal{F}_k)$

My attempt for 1:

So it's easy to see that $(X_n)$ is a martingal $E(X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=X_n+0=X_n$

Now we have to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X_{\infty}|^2)=0$ notice by Fatou
$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n-\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}X_k|^2)\leq \liminf\limits_{k\to \infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X_k|^2)=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\mathbb{E}(|X_k-X_{k-1}|^2)$$

And here I'm getting stucked. If I compute
$$\mathbb{E}(|X_k-X_{k-1}|^2)\leq \mathbb{E}(|X_k|^2+2|X_kX_{k-1}|+|X_{k-1}|^2)=1+2\mathbb{E}(|X_kX_{k-1}|)+1$$

Then I'm gettings obviously a sum that goes to infinity on the RHS.

---

My attempt for 2:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1}-X_k^2|\mathcal{F}_k)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k)-X_k^2=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1})-X_k^2$
$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{k+1}Y_ka_k\right)^2\right)-X_k^2$$

And here I get again stucked.

Comment: For the first question, what is $X$? Are you just trying to show $X_n$ converges to something in $L^2$?

Comment: @snarfblaat Yes. It says it converges to something in $L^2$ so $X$ should be $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} X_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$var(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2var(X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$ so if $\sum a_i^2<\infty$ then $\{X_n\}$ is $L^2$-bounded. Doob's $L^p$ martingale convergence theorem then gives an $L^2$ (and a.s.) limit. (Is this result available to you?) If $\sum a_i^2$ diverges then there can be no $L^2$ limit, 
$$E|X_n-X_\infty|^2=EX_n^2+EX_\infty^2-2E(X_nX_\infty)>EX_n^2-2||X_n||_2||X_\infty||_2+EX_\infty^2\to\infty
$$ 
as $n\to\infty$ (and $EX_n^2=var(X_n)\to\infty$).

For the second part (the "predictable compensator") I think you were on the right track,
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1}-X_k^2|\mathcal{F}_k)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X^2_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k)-X_k^2\\
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}((X_k+Y_{k+1})^2\mid\mathcal{F}_k)-X_k^2=
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2X_k\mathbb{E}(Y_{k+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_k)+\mathbb{E}(Y_{k+1}^2\mid\mathcal{F}_k)\\
=n\cdot var(Y_1)=n.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not quite sure, we did not have a convergence theorem about $L^p$ in general but we had the following theorem (without the professor giving a name): 
$$ $$
Let $(X_n)$ be a sub/supermartingal with $\sup\limits_{n\geq 0}\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)<\infty$, then it follows $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} X_n=X_{\infty}$ a.s. exists and $X_{\infty}\in L^1$ 
$\\$

Comment: And this one: Let $(Z_n)\in L^1(P)$ with $Z_n\to Z$ a.s. Then the following statement are equivalent:
$$1. Z_n\to Z \text{ in } L^1(P)$$
$$2. E(|Z_n|)\to E(|Z|)$$
$$3. \{Z_n\} \text{is uniform integrable}$$

My second question is, why can you do $E((|X-X_{\infty}|)^2)=E(X^2+X_{\infty}^2- 2|X_nX_\infty|)$?

Comment: From the result you mentioned (a.s. convergence) you can get $L_2$ convergence. Briefly: you know $|X_n-X_\infty|\to 0$ a.s. so use kolmogorov's maximal inequality and the $L_2$-boundedness to bound $E|X_n-X_\infty|^2$ and then apply dominated convergence. For your second question, you are right, the second absolute value bars should be parens, I will update (argument is the same).

Comment: I'm not quite following the argument for $|X_n-X_\infty|\to 0$, since I have not a super or submartingal here and the theorem applies not to martingal?

Comment: martingale is both a sub and sup-martingale

Comment: Ah sure, now I see it. So every theorem for submartingales is automatically also valid for martingales (and for supermartingales when looking at $-X$). Thank you very much for you help, I appreciate it!